# Building Limit in Lords of Waterdeep

Tags: lords-of-waterdeep

Why is there a limit to how many buildings can built by each player? I was the builder lady lord, using the Undermountain Expansion, and would have been about to build 12+ buildings, but game rules limit each player to 9. What is the reason for this limit?

Comment: Though this is speculation; it's quite possible that you just provided the exact reason... if you could build 12+ buildings; it would be way too good for the builder.

Comment: @GendoIkari I was wondering that too but didn't like that answer because I ended up losing the game. :)

Comment: Also, with only 8 rounds per game; how are you building that many? Normally only 1 building can be built per round; though there are certain ways to be allowed to choose a spot that someone else chose; or other ways to build a building without taking the building spot... but it seems unlikely that you'd be able to get so many.

Comment: I'm also very surprised that a builder with 9 buildings wouldn't win the game... in my experience, most people get either 16 or 20 bonus points from their role; you're talking about 36 points there, plus the benefit of owning so many buildings.

Comment: @GendoIkari with the Undermountain Expansion there's multiple quests that allow you to build buildings as the reward.

Comment: Ah ok... I've played Skullport but not Undermountain yet. I suppose that makes sense.

Comment: One other thought that doesn't serve as a real answer... since the base game had fewer ways to build more buildings; it was extremely unlikely that any 1 player could ever get more than 9 buildings anyway; so they only included 9 ownership markers. And this simply carried over into an actual rule that you can only have 9.

Comment: It's actually 6 VP per building, which with 9 buildings gives a whopping 54 points.

Comment: @bret 54 is pretty significant.  For most of the other lords you'd have to get 14 quests of your type to surpass that.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps Undermountain raises scores in general for all players, I don't know... but I'm used to people getting only 16 or 20 bonus points at the end; 54 is a lot. And I would think that bonus points from having buildings would be "worth more" than the other bonus points, because having that many buildings has other advantages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no building limits in Lords of Waterdeep as defined in the **Appendix 3: Clarifications** section in the rulebook of **Scoundrels of Skullport**:

> **Number of Buildings in Play**: You are not limited to the ten empty
>   spaces on the game board for Building tiles when putting Buildings into
>   play. Simply place any additional Buildings in a convenient place on or
>   near the board.

Also on the [official FAQ](http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2233) for Lords of Waterdeep:

**Can more than 10 Buildings be in play?**

> Yes. The number of empty Building spaces on the board is no limit to
>   the number of Buildings that can be in play during the game.

**EDIT:**

As for personal building limits, you *are* in fact limited to the number of building tokens you have, as defined in the [official FAQ](http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2233):

**Can you control more Buildings than you have control markers?**

> No. The number of control markers you have is the maximum number of
>   Buildings you can have in a single game.

This limit is also enforced on the iOS game.

Comment: The question was about how many buildings a single player can build. This does not answer it.

Comment: @Bret, the question is about why there's a building limit. An answer of "there's actually no limit" is correctly challenging the frame of the question.

Comment: Paul, the answerer is correct in that there is no overall building limit specified by the rules, but the question is about a per-player limit, which is specified by the rules to be 9; thus, this answer does not address the question.

Comment: The original question isn't worded perfectly which is why there is some confusion. My answer has been edited and now provides the answers to both questions (as it's still not 100% clear to me what the asker wants - was he limited to 9 because there's only 10 spaces and someone built a building already? Or is he limited to 9 because that's how many tokens he has).

Comment: I updated the question to add clarification. Either way though, the question was clearly "why", and this doesn't address "why" at all.

Comment: Same reason why the game only comes with X adventurers, or X gold tokens. The manufacturers pick arbitrary numbers that they think would feasibly be the maximum amount accumulated in any given game. Beyond developmental reasons, there is no real reason - and if boardgames.stackexchange is anything like the arqade, questions about development have no place. Therefore I assumed the asker intended on asking about the rules rather than a question about development.

Comment: @Othya I'm not completely sure about the rules given in meta here, but questions about game design are pretty common. Your comment here gives a possible reason (which I mentioned in my comment on the OP), but many games also say in the rules that components are not intended to be limiting, and they could have said you are allowed to build more than the 9 tokens the game comes with.

Comment: @GendoIkari your edit is correct and clarified what I was asking.